# Sherlock ActionItems unresponsive FIXED

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am attempting to load a new intent on the click of an actionitem on the SherlockActionBar. My code is as follows:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_plan) {
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_my_plans) {
            Intent MyPlansIntent = new Intent(this, MyPlans.class);
            startActivity(MyPlansIntent);
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_invites) {
            Intent InvitesIntent = new Intent(this, Invites.class);
            startActivity(InvitesIntent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }   

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_nav, paramMenu);
        return true;
    }
```

These are my imports:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.app.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

However, the clicks are unresponsive. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which did you import  `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem` or Android's native MenuItem?

Comment: Add a log output to see if `onOptionsItemSelected()` is being called at all. While you're at it, take out the `com.app.R` import, I have never seen it need to be explicitly imported and could be messing things up.

Comment: Did you try propagating the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` call to the super after doing your own inflating? I.e. `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)`.

Comment: Added the return call but still no lock. It doesn't seem like onOptionsItemSelected() is being called actually. Any reason why? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_nav, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent i;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.nav_plan:
        return true;

    case R.id.nav_my_plans:
        i = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME.this, MyPlans.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;

    case R.id.nav_invites:
        i = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME.this, Invites.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
     }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Switch statements seem to be no longer allowed see - http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

It was working fine with the native actionbar and switch though

Comment: Have you tried this code? Do you have any error? Please attach the logcat. Switch statement works with sherlockActionBar

Comment: @elbaretto: This is not true in this case, since the constants are from your own project. Only true for fields of library projects.